# How to add row header to JFace TableViewer?

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

How can I add "row headers" to a Jface `TableViewer`?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [`Grid`](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.php) widget from the [Nebula Project](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/).

[image]

It does support "row headers".

Answer (score 1):

A TableViewer does not by default provide this capability. But you can have a look at this [`snippet`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet234.java) to achieve something similar to a row header. This example uses two tables to make the first column fixed and rest of the columns horizontally scrollable. If you do not want fixed columns than you can just use different colors for columns to achieve the look and feel of a row header.